# Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable and concurrent requests

Tags: php, zend-framework, session

I'm currently using Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable to share session data across multiple machines.

I'm running into a problem with concurrent requests as per the following example. Request A and B run at the same time for the same user

1. Request A - Reads in the user's session data
2. Request B - Reads in the user's session data
3. Request B - Finishes by adding variable xyz to the session and writes the session data back to the database
4. Request A - Finishes and writes the original session values back to the database

Result. We lose the xyz variable. Note that Request A writes back to the database even though it hasn't changed the session variable. I assume this is because it needs to update the modified time of the session.

What is comes down to is that request A doesn't lock the session and it looks like Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable does not support session locking. Does anyone have any examples on how to fix this? Using a memcached or going back to file based sessions is not an option.

For the time being I've hacked the Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable write method to compare the modified date at read and at write and if different, don't write the session back to the database.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you see is as intended.  (That doesn't mean that it doesn't *suck*.)

The default file-based session handler actually keeps an exclusive lock on the session file between `session_start` and `session_write_close` / script end.  This allows only one of the user's requests to operate at once.

The PHP devs seem to want each custom session handler to deal with the locking problem independently.  This is not unreasonable, but it is a pain in the ass.

The solution you're using is probably safe and sane.  It's also superior to trying to establish locking in SQL, which can get troublesome when the script exits abnormally and can't release the lock.  You should consider fleshing out your custom code to make the locking optional, then submitting that code to the Zend Framework project, so others may benefit.

Comment: I know this is old stuff, but hacking a locking mechanism at database level should be achievable, using MySQL `GET_LOCK(session.id, timeout)` ...  these locks are dropped when database connection is closed. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/locking-functions.html#function_get-lock